# Can I disable the logging of a specific GameObject without modifying its script in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

For example, I have a `GameObject` A with the following script

```
public class A: MonoBehaviour
{
    private void Update()
    {
        Debug.Log("Log something");
    }
}
```

Can I disable the logging of A in another script so that the log of A is not shown in the console? **I do not want to modify script A.**

```
public class B: MonoBehaviour
{
    private void Start()
    {
        // Something like this
        FindObjectOfType<A>().DisableLogging();
    }
}
```

Is this idea viable?

Thank you very much.

Comment: I want to do this because I am using a plugin which logs a lot of things which I do not want to see.

Comment: Debug logging will be noop if you compile as release

Comment: @DanielA.White Really? I am on iOS. When I built the project, I set `Run in Xcode as` to `Release`. But the logs still showed up in Xcode's console. Did I miss any option?

Comment: @DanielA.White that's wrong! Debug log is all written into the [Player Log File](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LogFiles.html) regardless of the release config! That's why logging in an `Update` is strongly discouraged since it is extremely resource intense

Comment: And @OP no you can't really do that without modifying the script to some extent..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the previous discussions, I think the answer to this problem is no.

Answer (score 1):

Dependency inject your logging.

```
public interface ILogger _logger {
   void LogMessage(string message);
}

public class Logger : ILogger {
   public void LogMessage(string message)
   {
      Debug.Log(messsage);
   }
}

public class NoLogging : ILogger {
   public void LogMessage(string message)
   {
      //does nothing
   }
}

public class SomeObject {

  private ILogger _logger;

  public SomeObject(ILogger logger) {
      _logger = logger;
  }

  public void start()
  {
     _logger.log("Whatever");
  }

}

public class Program 
{ 
    public static void Main(string args) 
    {
        SomeObject objA = new SomeObject(new Logger());
        SomeObject objB = new SomeObject(new NoLogging());
    
        objA.Start();
        objB.Start();
    
    }
 }
```

Now if you have created an instance of SomeObject with a "Logger" in the constructor, it will now log the specific instance's data.

if you create an object with the "NoLogging" instance instance in the constructor, nothing will happen when logging is called.

EDIT: I didn't check this code compiles. So treat it as pseudo code.

Uh, also, if you need to make some logic for when an instances needs to have logging or not, (Or more verbose logging or not)
Simply use the factory pattern to generate your "SomeObject"'s based on said logic.

Comment: This is a good idea but under my scenario, the class which logs is not created by me. I want to disable the logging externally without modifying the script.

Comment: Not a problem, you are never actually disabling the logger, you are simply implementing a logger that does use the normal logger, and then another implementation that doesn't.

Or did I not understand your problem?

Comment: I think you misunderstood me. I want to put A into the scene intactly. It will still use `Debug.Log`.

Comment: You will never be able to modify the behaviour of A, without modifying A. This is impossible. 

Unless you change A, so you can EXTEND it, without modifying it. 
(Like shown in the example)

Because Class A, is a child of "MonoBehaviour". 
Thus A is immutable once instanced. 
Only if your behaviour can be injected, will you be able to change how A works.

Comment: I guess you are right. But in my case, I am using a script written by someone else with thousands of lines, I do not want to modify it...

Comment: If you are using code, you "fear" to change, you are setting up a dependency in your code, on code you don't understand, how will you test that it works? How will you verify that its behaviour is desired? 
You are causing yourself a lot of pain, by not being willing to implement something as basic as a dependency injection pattern to aliviate logging issues. Trust me, it is worth it.

Comment: Man I am using a 3rd party plugin to connect my app to a blockchain wallet. It is complicated  and that is why we use a plugin right? I cannot go through every line of it and refactor the whole class to a dependency injection pattern. I believe dependency injection pattern is useful and I will use it when I am writing my own code.

Comment: Fair enough, but if you aren't willing to make your plugin-code extendable, you are pulling in a dependency on a paradigm (or lack thereof) that will make it very difficult to validate your code.

Your are making unit testing, integration testing, (and by extension, regression testing) extremely difficult this way. 

And plugins MAY help, there is no promise they will. 
usually they only hide functionality you eventually will need to extend/modify eventually anyway.

Comment: I agree with you, it is always good to know more. The thing I am worrying about is that the plugin I am using is under Beta and they may update it very often. If I modify the code intensely, what should I do if they publish a new version? All my modifications will be replaced. That is why I don't want to modify it. That plugin is responsible for a very specific functionality (which is highly decoupled with my other code), so I think it is not very hard to test it.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a private boolean variable for MonoBehaviour *A*, *EnableLogging* and check if it's true before it logs anything.

```
public class A: MonoBehaviour
{
    private bool EnableLogging = true;
    public void SetLogging(bool value) { EnableLogging = value; }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (EnableLogging) { Debug.Log("Log something"); }
    }
}
```

then from another script

```
public class B: MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private A a;
    private void Start()
    {
        a.SetLogging(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't make the question clear. Your method works but I want to do it without modifying A, since A could be a plugin written by someone else.